# Aggregate values - SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, aggregate, sql-server-2019

I have several tables reflecting different modes of transportation a same person used on a particular day that go like this one. The variation it's in the number of replications of the CARD_ID, starting from 1 (meaning that the user just used ONE MODE of Transportation that day) to N (being N higher or equal than 8):

| CARD_ID | MODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1600096475 | TRAIN |
| 1600096475 | TRAIN |
| 1600096475 | SUBWAY |
| 1600096475 | SUBWAY |
| 1600096475 | TRAIN |
| 1600100953 | SUBWAY |
| 1600100953 | BUS |
| 1600100953 | BUS |
| 1600100953 | BUS |
| 1600100953 | SUBWAY |
| 1700000871 | BUS |
| 1700000871 | BUS |
| 1700000871 | BUS |
| 1700000871 | BUS |
| 1700000871 | BUS |
| 1700005073 | TRAIN |
| 1700005073 | TRAIN |
| 1700005073 | SUBWAY |
| 1700005073 | TRAIN |
| 1700005073 | BUS |

So user with CARD_ID 1700005073, for instance, on that day traveled by train, got off and got on another train line, got off and got on a subway and arrived to destination. Later on that day, got a subway and then a bus to his/her home (this is clearly a supposition).

What I need to do (and don't know how) are two different but somewhat related things:

1. Calculate % of the different Transportation MODES aggregated this way (let's assume T:TRAIN, S:SUBWAY and B:BUS):

| # of replications | # of records | # of CARD_IDs | T | S | B | T-S | T-B | S-B | T-S-B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 777,433 | 777,433 | 10 | 25 | 65 | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| 2 | 2,645,426 | 1,322,713 | 10 | 15 | 45 | 10 | 10 | 10 | N/A |
| 3 | 1,609,860 | 536,620 | 5 | 5 | 30 | 20 | 10 | 10 | 20 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

So the same user with CARD_ID 1700005073 had taken 3 Trains, 1 Subway and 1 Bus, which gives 1 for T-S-B, while user with CARD_ID 1700000871 had taken 5 Buses, which gives 1 for B (not %, just the number for that CARD_ID of transportation modes on that day). Of course other users do have different # of Transportation Modes, from just one (T, S or B) to multiple as in those previous examples.

For simplicity (mostly for the final user of these data) I have seven separated tables for each # of replications from 1 to 7 and their corresponding Transportation Mode (one per row), and an extra one for 8 or more replications, ordered by CARD_ID.

2. Calculate the amount of each Transportation MODE this way (let's assume T:TRAIN, S:SUBWAY and B:BUS):

| Total CARD_IDs | # of T | # of S | # of B | # of T-S | # of T-B | # of S-B | # of T-S-B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4,000,000 | 200,000 | 400,000 | 800,000 | 500,000 | 800,000 | 900,000 | 400,000 |

In a way, those are the grand totals on which point 1) was based.

All figures are just an example. If the different Modes for a single CARD_ID are disordered I can previously order them, I don't care for the moment of the day those modes took place. I'm just sure that all modes pertain to the same day for all CARD_IDs.

Is there a 'simple' way of performing these calculations? Or do I have to use cursors or similar or more performant tools to achieve this?

Any idea is more than welcomed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is a "replication"? If that is the number of unique transportation modes, why are there values for stand-alone `T`, `S`, `B` on line 2, and for anything other than `T-S-B` on line 3?

Comment: In plain words, a person can travel by bus just once a day and just because this person wants to make some exercise go back home by walking. In that case you will just have one mark for Bus (B) and none for the other 6 combinations.

A replication (at least for me) is the number of 'uses' of the Transportation Card (imagine an Oyster Card in London) per day. If you have an Oyster Card and go to work by Underground and return home by taxi, you will have just one mark on Subway (S), but if you take a Bus to return home, then the mark should go to S-B because you took both a Subway and a Bus

Comment: So you can use your card once , twice, three times or more per day, depending on which combinations of transport media you use. The quantity of combinations (1 to N) is what I called 'replications'. It could maybe not be the best of terms to use, but that was the aim of it.

Comment: As per your question @GSerg: if I have traveled by using just bus, OR subway, OR train (line 2), a mark (so to speak) will be put on either one of these, and NONE in the combinations T-S, T-B, S-B or T-S-B because I did just one use of the card. If I used the card twice in a day, it is NOT possible to have a mark on T-S-B because that implies a third (at least) use I did not make that day. Do these examples answer your question? If not I will try to explain it by using other examples / words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base query [will be](https://dbfiddle.uk/IAmQKc8B):

```sql
with data as (
  select *
  from (values 
    (1600096475, 'TRAIN'),
    (1600096475, 'TRAIN'),
    (1600096475, 'SUBWAY'),
    (1600096475, 'SUBWAY'),
    (1600096475, 'TRAIN'),
    (1600100953, 'SUBWAY'),
    (1600100953, 'BUS'),
    (1600100953, 'BUS'),
    (1600100953, 'BUS'),
    (1600100953, 'SUBWAY'),
    (1700000871, 'BUS'),
    (1700000871, 'BUS'),
    (1700000871, 'BUS'),
    (1700000871, 'BUS'),
    (1700000871, 'BUS'),
    (1700005073, 'TRAIN'),
    (1700005073, 'TRAIN'),
    (1700005073, 'SUBWAY'),
    (1700005073, 'TRAIN'),
    (1700005073, 'BUS')
  ) foo(CARD_ID, MODE)
),
data_grouped as (
  select CARD_ID, MODE, count(*) as replications
  from data
  group by CARD_ID, MODE
)
select
  CARD_ID,
  sum(replications) as replications,
  string_agg(MODE, '-') within group(order by MODE) as modes
from
  data_grouped
group by
  CARD_ID;
```

which will give you the following intermediate result:

| CARD_ID | replications | modes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1600096475 | 5 | SUBWAY-TRAIN |
| 1600100953 | 5 | BUS-SUBWAY |
| 1700000871 | 5 | BUS |
| 1700005073 | 5 | BUS-SUBWAY-TRAIN |

You can then query both of your things treating that as the base table:

- ```sql
  select replications, modes, count(*) * replications as [# of records], count(*) as [# of CARD_IDs]
  from [<that_thing>]
  group by replications, modes;
  ```

  | replications | modes | # of records | # of CARD_IDs |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 5 | BUS | 5 | 1 |
  | 5 | BUS-SUBWAY | 5 | 1 |
  | 5 | BUS-SUBWAY-TRAIN | 5 | 1 |
  | 5 | SUBWAY-TRAIN | 5 | 1 |
- ```sql
  select modes, count(*) as [# of CARD_IDs]
  from [<that_thing>]
  group by modes
  with rollup;
  ```

  | modes | # of CARD_IDs |
  | --- | --- |
  | BUS | 1 |
  | BUS-SUBWAY | 1 |
  | BUS-SUBWAY-TRAIN | 1 |
  | SUBWAY-TRAIN | 1 |
  | null | 4 |

(These are in the unpivoted form, [pivot them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) to have the `modes` as columns if you must.)

Comment: Thank you @GSerg, I'll check it out and return to you with comments or questions if necessary

Comment: I tried the base query and it worked Ok. When you state [<that_thing>] in the other two queries, what would it be? The result of the base query saved into a temp table? Could you please explain that to me? Thank you!

Comment: @FatsGordon There are multiple ways to substitute that in. If you click the dbfiddle link at the top, you will find the easiest one, where you can toggle between `select * from first_wanted_result` and `select * from second_wanted_result` on the last line.

Comment: I haven't noticed the link, I'm sorry. Thank you for all your help!